# I don't see the posted question under the tag in which I have posted

Tags: support, asking-questions, tag-search

I don't see the posted question under the tag in which I have posted immediately after my posting. It appears a little later, but it seems to be visible for others. What is happening here?

Comment: Can you post a link to the question you are talking about?

Comment: Probably caching.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900977/how-to-ignore-files-or-folders-in-a-svn-project - check this out, I don't see it now under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn

Answer (score 1):

As [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) mentioned above - this is almost definitely down to caching.

I can see your question and it appears under questions tagged `svn` also.
[image]

Tagged question list:
[image]

Comment: I have never been able to see my own question until a few minutes. Any ideas on how long this takes to invalidate the cache. The part I am confused with is if it doesn't show up for me because of the cache layer, then it should not show up for others also correct?

Comment: @user146862 As a note, the front page (stackoverflow.com) and the questions list (stackoverflow.com/questions) have different refresh rates - so sometimes it will be visible on one but not the other. This can explain some scenarios when you can't see it but apparently others can; they may be looking at a different page.